# What is the maximum size for svnadmin dump cmd can create

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump

I have svn repository which is larger than 10 GB in size. The svn running is SVN 1.6 on the server.I have migrate to SVN 1.9 using dump and load. **Has anyone created the dumpfile for repository size more than 10 GB**. If *SVNADMIN dump/load* does not support very big repositories, I have to find alternative approach like dumping based on revisions. I believe there should be some proven approach for larger repositories in svn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit for dumpfile.

Also note that you can use pipe for dump/load procedure:

> svnadmin dump src-repo | svnadmin load dest-repo

Comment: @ Ivan. I was not clear about size limit. It should then process my repo size. I have to dump and load to new server. I can use scp or ftp protocol to new server. What could be the best and fast way to transfer files without corruption. Any idea Iva.

Comment: svnadmin dump/load doesn't have known limits for dump file sizes. But it may took a while to load big dump file to repository though. Also please note that Subversion 1.9 will work fine with svn 1.6 FSFS repository.

Comment: so, will it work if source repo is copied directly to target server(using tar and scp for copy). The release notes says to have full features for svn1.9 the repo needs to be dump/load to destination server.

Comment: Yes, it will work if source repository has FSFS format (default from version 1.2 as far I remember). There is no features in svn 1.9 repo format: there are only some performance improvements. Changes in format before svn 1.9 improves performance in all configuration, while changes in svn 1.9 repo format may work slower without server configuration tuning.

Comment: It has fsfs in fs-type file. So, it should work in my case.